# mysql query to display each day between start_date and end_date fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with the following fields: start_date, end_date, channel, position, advertiser, user.

I want it to display like in the image (http://business-review-webinars.com/table.jpg). divided by the channel (software, ent app, open source...) and by the date (today, tomorrow, the day after, ...)

I know i can get results for each day with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2011-06-13' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

and that would display everything that's going on today. but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make it display neatly for each individual channel.

I guess i could do 1 query for each channel but i have around 50 channels, and if im gonna do 1 query for each day I would have hundreds of queries on the page.. not good i guess..

any ideas?

Comment: I would grab all the data needed and put query results in two dimensional array - `$table[channel][day][] = $row;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you essentially are looking for a "crosstab" view of your data.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/print_version.html

and

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

are some links I have in my bookmarks which may help you out.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed :)

SELECT channel,('2011-06-13' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS Date1, ('2011-06-14' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS Date2,('2011-06-15' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AS Date3 FROM table GROUP BY channel